# Why does screen corrupt like this?

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, ubuntu-mate, screen-corruption

I have Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS installed on an external HDD and I boot from it via USB. The problem is that the screen gets so corrupted that it's almost unreadable. See picture:

[image: picture of corrupted screen]

The screen's menu says that the monitor is set to 1280x720 and I can't change anything. I tried adding and activating 1920x1080 mode using `xrandr`, but it didn't work. Nothing changes, the mode is added, but the screen still looks like in the picture. Here's the output from `xrandr` when the screen is corrupted:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*DP-3 1280/160x720/90+0+0  DP-3

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1280x720      60.00*
```

However, I found a workaround for this issue: booting Ubuntu in safe mode and proceeding with the *Resume system boot* option fixes the problem. This is the `xrandr` output when the screen isn't corrupted:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +default 1920/508x1080/286+0+0  default

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

The computer I'm using is a Samsung DP500A2D with Intel HD Graphics 2500. [See full specs here](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/dp500a2d). I don't think it's a graphics card issue since Intel drivers are well-integrated into the Linux kernel. It's probably something with the built-in display itself. Can anyone explain that?

EDIT:

Output of `sudo lshw -C video`
:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of `dmesg | grep drm`:
*nothing*

Comment: Can you create a testuser? So you can see if it is a problem in system or $HOME.

Comment: @nobody I'm sure it's the system bcs this corruption occurs when I boot the system. Manufacturer's logo, Ubuntu Mate loading screen, etc. - everything is corrupted. Only GRUB remains normal.

Comment: can you show `sudo lshw -C video` and `dmesg | grep drm` Please add both to your question.

Comment: @nobody Output added, have a look

Comment: Where is the module? `sudo modprobe -v i915`  please paste `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`  to https://paste.ubuntu.com/  and show also cat `/proc/cmdline`

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title in this question answer site. The green check mark ✅ is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to kinda solve this. The thing is that newer kernels either do not have this driver included or they do not load it or maybe something else. The same screen corruption issue occured while using Porteus distro. It worked when I installed kernel 4.9.12.

Also, here are links to Linux Mint forum describing the same issue with the same all-in-one computer (Samsung DP500A2D):

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=385111

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=334172

EDIT: It is even weirder: I tried booting Linux Mint from external SSD drive on this computer and the screen got corrupted but then I used "recovery mode" from "advanced options" in grub and selected "resume" and it worked. I remember it worked for kernel 5.x as well